# Pop3Client RetrieveMessageObject() includes everything except body in .net-core application

Tags: c#, .net-core, pop3

I am creating a .net core application that accesses an inbox using an ActiveUp.Net Pop3Client.  I originally started by creating an API that would be accessible by the application but then decided I would make it into a core package that I import into the project with NuGet.

This has worked great with everything except for one issue.  The body of the emails does not seem to come through in the application when accessing the email from the NuGet package.  It worked perfectly fine when testing the API but even though most of the code is copied directly over it doesn't seem to get the body.

here is the function that creates and calls the pop3client.   I added console write lines to see if any of the body fields that I found return anything and they all return blank for every email.  It successfully pulls back every other field that I request which is also why I am confused.  It seems like it would have to be some sort of configuration issue.  Is there something I am missing here?

```
        private IEnumerable<Email> GetEmail()
        {
            Pop3Client Client = new Pop3Client();
            try
            {
                Client.ConnectSsl(_ms, _pt, _lg, _ps);
                List<Email> messages = new List<Email>();

                    for (int n = 1; n <= Client.MessageCount; n++)
                    {
                        Message message = Client.RetrieveMessageObject(n);
                        Email messageDetails = new Email();
                        messageDetails.uid = message.MessageId;
                        messageDetails.sentFrom = message.From.Email;
                        messageDetails.subject = message.Subject;
                        messageDetails.body = message.BodyHtml.TextStripped.Trim();
                        if (n > 225)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("text: " + message.BodyHtml.Text);
                            Console.WriteLine("text stripped: " + message.BodyHtml.TextStripped);
                            Console.WriteLine("body text: " + message.BodyText.Text);
                            Console.WriteLine("body text stripped: " + message.BodyHtml.TextStripped);
                        }
                        messageDetails.date = message.Date;
                        messages.Add(messageDetails);
                    }
                return messages;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (Client.IsConnected)
                {
                    Client.Disconnect();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Dont `Console.WriteLine`, instead place a breakpoint and inspect everything with a debugger. Also don't write out the exception, VS will give you specifics regarding the exception if you let it throw.

Comment: I am working through this right now as I haven't formatted an application like this before but this function is in a solution that isn't executable by itself but rather is executed within another application.  So I can't get it to actually debug and hit breakpoints within the NuGet package.  If that makes sense.  If there is a way to do this let me know.

Comment: I have added this code along with the whole core application that was being added directly to the application so I can debug.  When I debug that it seems the Client.RetrieveMessageObject doesn't get the body or the body does not map correctly.

Comment: it seems that the issue lies within the retrieve message function.  I seem to have fixed it by switching to using mimekit instead up activeup.net